# How to display Core Data records?

Tags: ios, core-data

My CoreData model contains many different tables with relationships.

1. Is there a library I could add to my iOS project which can be called to display a modal view with a simple CRUD Interface of all these tables ?
2. If not, is there a simple OSX application which displays this CRUD interface with mom model and sqlite files in input ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a library called [DataCenter on GitHub](https://github.com/danielctull/DataCenter) that might do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command line tool `sqlite3` to examine a data store on the desktop. Don't even think about modifying the data store, though; you should *only* modify the data store with Core Data.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is!  Check out the built-in [NSFetchedResultsController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html), or [SKTableViewDataSource](https://github.com/aopsfan/SKTableViewDataSource).  Both of these APIs are meant to display very pretty index-style `UITableViews`, and will handle updates nicely as well.  You'll need to make your own forms and detail view controllers though.